# custom class story board uisegmentcontrol uistepper

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboard, uisegmentedcontrol, uistepper

i've created a subclass of an UisegmentControl and added to my project.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MMcustomsegment : UISegmentedControl

@end
```

on the storyboard i've chose the right custom class on the identity inspector.
But when i run it i've the standard layout of the segmentcontrol...

if i add my custom segment programatically in this way

```
MMcustomsegment *mySegmentedControl = [[MMcustomsegment alloc]
initWithItems:tipoord];
mySegmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(20, self.view.frame.size.height - 160, 280, 29);
mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
[mySegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];

[self.view addSubview:mySegmentedControl];
```

it works!!

same staff for my custom uistepper

I really don't know how to solve it.
thanks

ps sorry for my bad english

Comment: Have you hooked up the elements you created in Storyboard with the associated properties in your custom class?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is anything wrong with what you have done in the storyboard.
If I understand you correctly you have done like i do in the image below, I have a subclass of `UILabel` called `JSLabel`, changing to my custom class like this:

[image: Adding JSLabel]

I think you might have some error in the subclass. Maybe you need to fix something there.
Can't help you more without more info about your subclass.

Good luck!